# Connecting Ne555 chip's 7 discharge pin directly to supply

Tags: 555

I'm building a adjustable frequently generator with ne555 timer .
But I don't want duty cycle to change with frequency so Can I connect the 7 discharge pin directly to supply and add a potentiometer to adjust charge and discharge times .
I think discharge pin can create short circuit and it will burn the chip ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbSRug.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Normally green wire is resistor but I want to remove the resistor and connect discharge pin directly to supply

Comment: A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: My country don't let me use the website but I'll try to use VPN

Comment: How is it supposed to oscillate with no discharge path from the capacitor?

Comment: I probably draw the circuit wrong but I got my answer so problem solved

Comment: Leave the Discharge pin open, and connect the pot to pin 3 instead of the supply. To get 50% duty cycle add a 1k pullup resistor from pin 3 to the supply, or use the CMOS 7555 version which has symmetrical output voltage. Pot should have a 10k resistor in series to set minimum resistance.

Comment: I don't want to be asking too much but can you send me a schematic or something ? Because I don't know how the circuit going to work without discharge pin 7 is left open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. When the output is on, the discharge pin will connect to ground, through the chip. You will then have your supply connected to ground, through the chip. This will either cause the supply voltage to drop so the chip doesn't work properly, or cause the chip to overheat and burn out, or both.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve same result without burn anything ?

Comment: Maybe I can add 1k ohm resistor to discharge pin and use 100k-500k potentiometer so 1k extra resistance won't affect the duty cycle ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. You can Google search for different 555 circuits. To get a 50% duty cycle I used a circuit that included diodes, but I don't remember the exact circuit right now.

Comment: If you take care to use a CMOS version of the 555 you there's a 50% duty cycle circuit that will let you adjust frequency with one pot.  But it doesn't work on the TTL versions (like the original NE555).